# internal interface implementation in a public interface

Tags: c#, interface

```
internal interface ICommand
{
    // some methods...
}

public interface IProject
{
    // some other methods...

    ICommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

I think it is clear enough. Compiler doesn't allow this due to accessibility. Is there any way to do it? Or should I change the structure?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you help us understand the use case we might come up with much better alternatives for you.

Comment: @jgauffin He just wants it that way !!!

Comment: @ToanNguyen Looks like you took the naughty pill today

Comment: @jgauffin Just for fun :D

Comment: In the project, IProject is a interface that is used commonly. I can't change its accessibility. But I'm allowed to add new properties like ICommand. But due to policies ICommand has to be internal. That's why I want it in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All members of a interface must be the same accessibility or less restrictive than the interface itself. So you can not have a internal type in a public interface.

However what you can do is have a *derived* interface that is more restrictive than its parent, that derived interface could contain internal members.

```
internal interface ICommand
{
    // some methods...
}

public interface IProject
{
    // some other methods...
}

internal interface IProjectWithCommands : IProject
{
    ICommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best one which will fix my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it an `abstract class`.. which will allow accessibility modifiers on it:

```
internal interface ICommand
{
    // some methods...
}

public abstract class Project
{
    // some other methods...

    internal ICommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to still enforce a contract while controlling some portion of accessibility. However, this may or may not suit you as it will break your inheritance abilities.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But it is not possible to change it from interface to abstract class.

Comment: _"Or should I change the structure?"_. That sort of implied that you could do such a thing..

Comment: Because you chose an `abstract` class, I wonder if you intended to make the property `Command` `abstract`? Because as it stands now, it is a concrete and non-virtual automatically generated property (with "invisible" backing field) and the inheritors cannot change the implementation (or get rid of the backing field).